# how to convert Array of buffers to Audio File

Tags: javascript, node.js

`chunks` is Array of Buffers i marge them by: `Buffer.concat()` but when i convert them to wav by lame i got wav file but theirs nothing in it

```js
const Lame = require("node-lame").Lame;
let chunks = [];

const audioStream = receiver.createOpusStream(user);

audioStream.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
    chunks.push(chunk);
});

.......

var buf = Buffer.concat(chunks);
console.log(buf.length);

const decoder = new Lame({
    "output": "./demo.wav"
}).setBuffer(buf);

decoder.decode()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('done');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I not familiar with the npm package.

Try this.

```
const Lame = require("node-lame").Lame;
let chunks = [];


const audioStream = receiver.createOpusStream(user);

// assumption that your buffer is correct
audioStream.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);
    chunks.push(chunk);
});

const encoder = new Lame({
    "output": "./demo.wav",
    "bitrate": 192 // what ever bitrate
}).setBuffer(buf);

encoder.encode()
    .then(() => {
        // Encoding finished
        console.log('done');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Something went wrong
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: i got this error:

```
Error: lame: Warning: unsupported audio format
    at Socket.progressStdout (C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\أحمد السيد\test\node_modules\node-lame\lib\build\Lame.js:245:52)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

Comment: could be a corrupted file. Try rm -rf node_modules and `npm install`

Comment: i got the same thing :/